# Split an array up into pieces in php

Tags: php, arrays

Assume you have the following array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

How would I split this up in php so that I have:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] [7]] // divide by three.
```

I know it would be something like `array % 3` but i'm not actually sure ...

Ideas?

Comment: Using PHP's built-in [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a special php function *array_chunk()* ([learn more](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php))

```
 <?php
      $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Honda", "Mercedes", "Opel");
      // second argument defines how many chunks you gonna make
      print_r(array_chunk($cars, 3));
 ?>
```