# Split flat array into multiple arrays with specific counts dictated by another array of integers

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have an array of dynamic length L1. I need to split this array into L2 number of arrays each having `LEN[i]` numbers from the original array.

Input arrays:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    
$LEN = [3,3,4]
```

`$LEN` states how many elements each new array should contain. The 3 arrays will be:

```
$a1 = [1,2,3]

$a2 = [4,5,6]

$a3 = [7,8,9,10]
```

I have tried a lot of ways but nothing seems to be working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: array_chunk https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php almost gets you there.

Comment: Post your attempts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split an array up into pieces in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484074/split-an-array-up-into-pieces-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need such a variable array length of chunks then you can create your own functionality using simple `foreach` and `array_splice` like as

```
$array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

$arr = [3,3,4];
$result_arr = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $result_arr[$k] = array_splice($array,0,$v);
}
print_R($result_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works. How can i access individual element of the result_arr?

Comment: Thats the simplest thing that you need to do over here

Comment: you can access it value with `echo $result_arr[0][0];` and so on.

Comment: Yeah figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$input      = range(1,11);
$chunk_size = 3;
$output     = array_chunk($input, $chunk_size);

// If we can't chunk into equal sized parts merge the last two arrays.
if(count($input) % $chunk_size) {
    $leftovers = array_pop($output);
    $last      = array_pop($output);
    array_push($output, array_merge($last, $leftovers));
}

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 6,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 7,
    1 => 8,
    2 => 9,
    3 => 10,
    4 => 11,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function SplitLike($array, $groups)
{
   $result = [];
   $left = count($array);
   foreach ($groups as $i => $group) {
       $result[$i] = array_slice($array, count($array) - $left, $group);
       $left -= $group;
   }
   return $result;
}
```